# express-graphql - subroutes matching parent route

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

So I have the following routes: `/creator/item` and `/creator/item/price`. Both the schemas of the two routes have a mutation called `updateOne`. However, when I call the route of `/creator/item/price` it matches `/creator/item` instead.

Is this intended? Is there a workaround or do I have to make a completely unique path name for it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the order of definition matters.

Before:

```
// - item
const item_schema =
    require("./graphql/creator/items")
app.use(
    "/creator/item", 
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema: 
            item_schema,
        graphiql: 
            env !== "production",
        formatError
    })
)
const item_price_schema =
    require("./graphql/creator/item/prices.js")
app.use(
    // "/creator/updateOne/price", 
    "/creator/item/price", 
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema: 
            item_price_schema,
        graphiql: 
            env !== "production",
        formatError
    })
)
```

After:

```
const item_price_schema =
    require("./graphql/creator/item/prices.js")
app.use(
    // "/creator/updateOne/price", 
    "/creator/item/price", 
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema: 
            item_price_schema,
        graphiql: 
            env !== "production",
        formatError
    })
)
// - item
const item_schema =
    require("./graphql/creator/items")
app.use(
    "/creator/item", 
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema: 
            item_schema,
        graphiql: 
            env !== "production",
        formatError
    })
)
```